# Get ID from closest feature in different layer

Tags: fields-attributes, arcgis-online, spatial-join, arcgis-collector, arcade

ArcGIS Collector (Android)

ArcGIS Online

---

Scenario:

Users create and update features in a point FC via Collector.

Upon creation/update, I want Collector to:

1. Automatically get the ASSET_ID value from the closest feature in a line FC.
2. Insert the value from the line FC into an ASSET_ID field in the points FC.

What would it take to configure ArcGIS Collector to automatically perform a spatial operation like this?

Answer (score 2):

Since you can't extend or customize Collector itself:

1. Maybe using a SOI ([Server Object Interceptor](https://enterprise.arcgis.com/en/sdk/latest/windows/82aeee25-39c5-4c10-8666-bb37fa58e9e4.html)) to intercept the point feature add/update event, then execute some custom code such as the Near() geoprocessing method to return the closest line feature.
2. Have some sort of SQL trigger, to calculate the nearest line using the built-in spatial functions of the database.

Comment: Is it possible to do this in ArcGIS Online (hosted)? Pardon my ignorance, but isn't the ArcGIS Online DB inaccessible -- since it's some sort of Azure or AWS PostgreSQL db? Or have I misunderstood?

Comment: ArcGIS Online does not provide access to create/update any intercepter or DB access for SQL triggers.

Comment: but ESRI Rest services dose.

Comment: @MuhammadImranSiddique Do we need a GeoAnalytics Server license to use it?

Comment: I dont know, I can check for you.

Answer (score 1):

Use Smart Edit Widget in ArcGIS Online Web Application builder